# What are ELF magnetic fluctuations?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am studying [these](http://www.issibern.ch/forads/sr-001-08.pdf) notes about minimum and maximum variance analysis for multi-spacecraft data. At page 20 the authors write:

> Current layers observed in space often contain ELF magnetic
>   fluctuations and various short-duration substructures of substantial
>   amplitude.

What are *ELF magnetic fluctuation*?

Comment: Extremely Low Frequency